# How to use ByteArrayOutputStream and DataOutputStream simultaneously in Java?

Tags: java, wrapper, bytearrayoutputstream, dataoutputstream

I'm having quite a problem here, and I think it is because I don't understand very much how I should use the API provided by Java.

I need to write an `int` and a `byte[]` into a `byte[]`.

I thought of using a `DataOutputStream` to solve the data writing with `writeInt(int i)` and `write(byte[] b)`, and to be able to put that into a byte array, I should use `ByteArrayOutputStream` method `toByteArray().`

I understand that this classes use the Wrapper pattern, so I had two options:

```
DataOutputStream w = new DataOutputStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
```

or

```
ByteArrayOutputStream w = new ByteArrayOutputStream(new DataOutputStream());
```

but in both cases, I "loose" a method. in the first case, I can't access the `toByteArray()` method, and in the second, I can't access the `writeInt()` method.

How should I use this classes together?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream w = new DataOutputStream(baos);

w.writeInt(100);
w.write(byteArray);

w.flush();

byte[] result = baos.toByteArray();
```

Actually your second version will not work at all. `DataOutputStream` requires an actual target stream in which to write the data. You can't do `new DataOutputStream()`. There isn't actually any constructor like that.

Comment: I've always wondered, is there really I reason to flush a wrapped `ByteArrayOutputStream`?

Comment: there isn't but you never know the behaviour of a wrapper. It could actually buffering something so I flush the wrapper by habit :). If it's a pass-thru wrapper it shouldn't hurt.

Comment: can you declare the byteArray variable? and what actually w.write(byteArray); do?

Comment: ah its working now, there is some problem on my hex editor (i wrote it to file just to prove it and it works)

Answer (score 3):

Could you make a variable to hold on to the ByteArrayOutputStream and pass it into the DataOutputStream.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);
dos.writeInt(1);
byte[] result = dos.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the former case - wrap `DataOutputStream` around the `ByteArrayOutputStream`. Just make sure you save the reference to the `ByteArrayOutputStream`. When you are finished, close() or at least flush() the `DataOutputStream` and then use the toByteArray method of the `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a stream approach if you connect your outputstream to an inputstream through a `PipedInputStream`/`PipetOutputStream`. Then you will consume the data from the inputstream.

Anyway if what you need to do is simple and doesn't not require a stream approach I would use a `java.nio.ByteBuffer` on which you have

- `put(byte[] src)` for your `byte[]`
- `putInt(int value)`
- and `byte[] array()` to get the content

Answer (score 1):

You don´t need more like this

```
Example exampleExample = method(example); 
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); marshaller.marshal(exampleExample , baos);
Message message = MessageBuilder.withBody(baos.toByteArray()).build();
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please consider **formatting** `code` with markdown so it's easier to read. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

The Integer class has a method to get the byte value of an int.
[`Integer.byteValue()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#byteValue())