# DataOutputStream to Array

Tags: java, arrays, string, dataoutputstream

Is there any way to write DataOutputStream content to an `Array` or a `String` regardless which type of data it contains?

```
DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(String dataPath)));
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried storing it in an array as an object or parsing whatever it contains to a string?

Comment: No, working on the second right now.Any idea how to parse?

Comment: You can  use ByteArrayOutputStream as mentioned in the below link *http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984538/how-to-use-bytearrayoutputstream-and-dataoutputstream-simultaneously-java*

Comment: @JürgenK. I wasn't sure that they would work, I haven't tried them, it was just a quick thought. What is the kind of contents of the stream? Just characters of text?

Comment: @JürgenK. If they are sent as an actual double type, then this wouldn't work unless you explicitly knew when it was going to be a double or not. If you did, you would use: Double.parseDouble(input) and then for the strings you could simply cast them as a string (String) because they hold that type already.

Comment: @Sunil. I don't think this works. It a actually a solution to a different question

Comment: @James. Which input do you mean?

Comment: @JürgenK. whatever is coming from your stream.

Comment: @James. Well, thanks for that but it still doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ByteArrrayOutputStream.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
OutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(baos);
os.write(...);
byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
String dataAsString = new String(data, "UTF-8"); // or whatever encoding you are using
```

You may use the following strategy as well:

```
class CompositeOutputStream implements OutputStream {
    private OutputStream first,second;
    public CompositeOutputStream(OutputStream first, OutputStream second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second=second;
    }

    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        first.write(b);
        second.write(b);
    }

    // etc.
}
```

Use with:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
OutputStream os = new CompositeOutputStream(new DataOutputStream(...), baos);
os.write(...);
byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
String dataAsString = new String(data, "UTF-8"); // or whatever encoding you are using
// etc.
```

The "baos" is only a "mirror" of what's got written to your original DataOutputStream

You still need to handle exceptions correctly, and be carefull about the amount of data written (holding everything in memory may lead to out of memory), etc.

Comment: Is it possible to copy the content of the DataOutPutStream to the ByteArrayOutputStream? Using something else than the DataOutputStream is otherwise not an option

Comment: You mean, after everything has been written, you need to get a "log" of what has been produced? I'm afraid nothing like that exists in the base lib, but you may implement it yourself easily (with a composite pattern). See my edit

Comment: Yes, the final result is already inside of the DataOutPutStream. I want to get it without writting it to a file.

Comment: Actually i don't understand how your compositeOutputStream can might work=(

Comment: Each time you write something to the first stream, you write the same thing to the other. after everything has been written, you may use the reference to the given OS to retrieve the data. The problem is, after a data has been "flushed" on a stream (either a file, a network, etc), the stream does not hold that data anymore (it got garbage collected) thus you can not get it anymore

Comment: * only ByteArrayOutputStream provides you a way the get an history of what has been written